# addTimer: causing SIGABRT?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

In xcode

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:auto_panic_upadte_secs 
                            invocation:panicPendingTickInvocation repeats:FALSE];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

It gets past these lines of code, But as soon as I run it just SIGABRTs without/before my invocation happening.

Any idea to do this?

Comment: Show us the declaration of `auto_panic_upadte_secs` and how you create the invocation.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to retain the arguments to your NSInvocation with the method

```
[panicPendingTickInvocation retainArguments];
```

To stop and autoreleased arguments from being released before you timer firers.

Comment: I ended up just changing the code to:



[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:intervalSecs target:self 
  selector:@selector(panicPendingTick) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

and that worked